# I cannot make deeplink to work Gx. 18.4 .net Android native

Tags: genexus

Im trying the easiest examples of deeplink but I cannot make any progress.
Tried both auto and manual settings.

My Native app is deployed to gx cloud.

In the Main Objet I pasted the gx cloud url with its virtual domain at the Deep Link Base Url:

```
https://apps5.genexus.com/Idb6fdcb8d4axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
```

I created a new webpanel with a "hello world" textblock with the name viewtest

I can reach it with chrome: https://apps5.genexus.com/Idb6fdcb8d4axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/viewtest.aspx

I created a new panel with an "it worked" textblock and choosed the viewtest object in the Deeplink name property. the Gx:ViewTest label appears.

After deploying again de app, I tried opening the same link from an email and it opens directly with chrome. I tried both with the emulator and with my mobilephone.

Then I tried the manual approach using the deeplink.handle event.
Tried a few of the simplest and more complex codes, but I never get the OS tho display the "open with" message.

I reviewed the DeepLinkU6 shared Kb and cannot find any difference with my implementation.

¿What else could I try?
thanks.